# Where I can find the source code for the android document on developer.android.com/guide?

Tags: android, doc

I mean the source for the document, like markdown or something like, not the HTML files in the SDK folder. Is it open-source ?

Comment: you mean android source code http://source.android.com/

Answer (score 0):

Open Android SDK Manager. Select an Android version, like Android 4.3. Check sources for Android SDK and install. Then you can find source code located at %ANDROID_HOME%\sdk\sources\android-18. Is this what you want?